# Cannot set correct edit permissions in Meteor.methods

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullcalendar, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to set permissions for add, edit and delete through my Meteor methods.
I'm working on a calendar that users can add events to and there events are visible to all, but an event can only be updated or removed by the event owner.

So far I have it to where only the logged in users can insert items and when it's inserted a `createdBy:currentUserId` value is assigned, but after an item is inserted I want it to be setup to where only the user that created the event can update or remove it. This should come from the `createdBy` value that is stored when the item is created

I've read through the documentation but still can't get this to work. In my methods I have been setting a var with `var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();` and I have been trying to restrict edits and deletes through the method with `if({createdBy: currentUserId}) {allow edit and delete here}`

Everything I have tried so far does not prevent other users from deleting or editing other users events.

I'm only posting the code that's relevant to edit as i'm assuming edit and delete will be almost identical. I am very new to Meteor, so any and all help is appreciated!

UPDATE! I'm trying to switch my `createdBy` into my method like @Yann recommended, but it will not allow the user ID to be placed and just returns an error of `createdBy` is required . The code I'm trying is

```
Meteor.methods({
  addEvent( event ) {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var createdBy = currentUserId;
    check( event, {

      title: String,
      start: String,
      end: String,
      type: String,
      guests: Number
    });

    try {
      return Events.insert( event, {
        $set: createdBy
      });
    } catch ( exception ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error( '500', `${ exception }` );
    }
  }
});
```

END OF UPDATE

The add edit modal code

```
Template.addEditEventModal.events({
  'submit form' ( event, template ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();


    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' ),
        submitType = eventModal.type === 'edit' ? 'editEvent' : 'addEvent',
        eventItem  = {
           createdBy: currentUserId,
          title: template.find( '[name="title"]' ).value,
          start: template.find( '[name="start"]' ).value,
          end: template.find( '[name="end"]' ).value,
          type: template.find( '[name="type"] option:selected' ).value,
          guests: parseInt( template.find( '[name="guests"]' ).value, 10 )
        };

    if ( submitType === 'editEvent' ) {
      eventItem._id   = eventModal.event;
    }

    Meteor.call( submitType, eventItem, ( error ) => {
      if ( error ) {
        Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
      } else {
        Bert.alert( `Event ${ eventModal.type }ed!`, 'success' );
        closeModal();
      }
    });
  },
   'click .delete-event' ( event, template ) {
    let eventModal = Session.get( 'eventModal' );
    if ( confirm( 'Are you sure? This is permanent.' ) ) {
      Meteor.call( 'removeEvent', eventModal.event, ( error ) => {
        if ( error ) {
          Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
        } else {
          Bert.alert( 'Event deleted!', 'success' );
          closeModal();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The update method

```
Meteor.methods({

  editEvent( event ) {

    check( event, {
      _id: String,
      createdBy: String,
      title: Match.Optional( String ),
      start: String,
      end: String,
      type: Match.Optional( String ),
      guests: Match.Optional( Number )
    });
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
  if({createdBy: currentUserId}){
    try {
      return Events.update( event._id, {
        $set: event
      });
    } catch ( exception ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error( '500', `${ exception }` );
    }
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

Firstly, `Events.insert( event, {$set: createdBy })` makes no sense. You're trying to do a `$set` at the same time as an insert and your `createdBy` is just a string.

Try:

```
Meteor.methods({
  addEvent( event ) {
    check( event, {    
      title: String,
      start: String,
      end: String,
      type: String,
      guests: Number
    });

    try {
      event.createdBy = Meteor.userId();
      return Events.insert(event);
    } catch ( exception ) {
      throw new Meteor.Error( '500', `${ exception }` );
    }
  }
});
```

Later in your updated method you have `if({createdBy: currentUserId})` which also makes no sense as it will always evaluate to true (you're basically writing `if(object)`. Use instead:

```
if( event.createdBy === Meteor.userId() )
```

Note that allow/deny rules do *not* apply to server methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on inserting that user Id! One question I changed my update method to use `if( event.createdBy === currentUserId )` but it seems as if it can not get the Id of the current user. Any idea on what could be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just tried `if( event.createdBy === Meteor.userId() )` and still nothing console.log on the if statement also returns nothing. Could there be something preventing it from getting the userId?

Comment: If the user is not logged in then Meteor.userId() will return undefined.

Comment: Are you using imports? If so you will need to import the Meteor object.

Comment: User is logged in and I'm not using imports. I just tested by removing the `if( event.createdBy === Meteor.userId() )`  and I console logged Meteor.userId (), this returned the userId as it should. But I noticed something interesting. It seems as if every time I try to delete or update an event it's actively trying to change the user ID to the current user, also when I try to delete an item it attempts to call the insert method and update methods. I believe this may be the problem. Does this lie somewhere in the `add-edit-event-modal.js`code. I know that code is somewhat linked together.

Comment: Hard to tell but you should probably do `event.stopPropagation()` in your event handlers to avoid events being sent to multiple handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Go check the allow mechanism to set your allow rules for insert, update and remove.
https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-allow

Regs

Comment: Would it be an issue with that? It's not that edits can't be made, my issue is that when I set permissions it still allows any logged in user to make edits. The only thing that it is blocking so far is logged out users

Comment: Could i just be using the wrong code to set those permissions?

Comment: Change your if statement to event.createdBy === Meteor.userId()

Comment: Changed if statement to `if(event.createdBy === currentUserId)` still does not prevent editing from other users.

Comment: and tried `if(event.createdBy === Meteor.userId())` still no success

Comment: Did you remove the insecure package ?

Comment: Yes it has been removed. That was my first thought and I double checked to make sure.

Comment: The createdBy field should not be set on client side as you du in form submit event. Because you always set the value to current user id, it would always match the logged userid. Always set the createdBy on server side.

Comment: That makes sense. But why when I view the collection from console it shows the original users ID? Isn't that what the permission is looking at?